# Paypal $_REQUEST[ ] array values

Tags: php, paypal

I have created one subscription form and in there I have number of cycles the payment will run .

```
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="<?php echo $total_cycle; ?>">
```

Can we get the value of `srt` field with the `$_REQUEST[ ]` of PayPal.

What values actually `$_REQUEST` array returns in PayPal ? I have not found a definitive answer to it.

If someone can help ? Thanks

Comment: I have used print_r($_REQUEST) to print the values , still i dont see the subscription time period value stored in srt.